# Rest APIs to support forgot password functionality which span to multiple steps

Tags: rest

I have to develop a Rest API for forgot password functionality which span in three different workflow i.e.

1. First I need to verify user input for name, email and phone. If all are valid and belongs to that particular user, will send some security code to user's email and phone.
2. If first step is success. Need to capture security codes(from email and phone) provided by user and validate those.
3. If second step is success. Capture user's new password and send a request to save that new password.

Now I can create three different Rest APIs for above three steps and perform the task whatever required for that particular API.

If I am calling this forget password from a UI, in that case it will be responsibility of the UI client to take care of the sequence of the API's being get called to complete the whole process. But from API perspective user can skip the initial 2 API calls and directly call the 3rd API which save/overwrite the existing password with new password.

How can I enforce the sequence of steps(APIs) being called even if consumer of the API's is not a UI rather I am using it by some Rest browser client?

Answer (score 0):

You should merge both second and third step.

Basically, we should receive the validation token with the new password request to confirm if it's a valid operation.

First step, the user request a "forgot password" operation and you send the token to his email/phone. You shouldn't send that information in the response of this request for security reasons.

Second step, the user introduce the token (or open an link with the token in the querystring, etc) and introduce the new password. The request that will go the API will contain both the token and the new password. If the token is valid for that user, you must update the password.

Comment: I thought the same to combine 2nd and 3rd step as It would automatically enforce user to first provide his/her details so that tokens can be send and without those token the second API won't be able to update the password as tokens are required. Tokens are not being sent as part response of the first request, those will be sent to users email and phone.

Comment: I already have the API for validating the codes received on email and phone. Is it fine to make a call to API i.e. lets say save new password and internally from this API's implementation I am doing password format verification and calling another Rest API to perform codes validation?

Comment: i would remove the API for token validation and add the token to the request of the password change and validate it internally.